# What is a good approach to develop a synchronous/blocking and an asynchrounous/non-blocking library-api in parallel? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, api-design

*I rewrote this question, because the old version was obviously misleading.
Please read the text and make shure you understood what I'm asking for. If
there is still anything left in the dark I'll modify this question for clarity.
Just inform me.*

One of my projects is to port a library from Python to JavaScript.
The Python library is entirely blocking/synchronous when it comes to I/O
and such. This is of course perfectly normal for Python code.

I plan to port the synchronous/blocking methods *as they are* to JavaScript.
This has several reasons and whether or not it's worth the effort is a
**good** but **different** question.

**Additionally** I wan't to add an asynchronous/non-blocking api.

Think of it like the fs module in node where there are i.e. `fs.open` and
`fs.openSync` coexisting.

The library is pure JavaScript and will run in Node and in the Browser.

### The question is what a good/the best approach for the development of these two coexisting APIs would be.

I believe its good to have the same thing happening in one place only.
Hence an approach where some parts of the implementation could be shared would be preferable.
*Not at any price of course, that's why I'm asking.*

I had a proposal for an approach in here, but I'm going to post it as a
possible answer. However, I'm waiting for some serious discussion to happen
before I decide what I accept as an answer.

#### So far approaches are:

- implement both apis separately and *definetly* use promises for the asynchronous functions.
- use something like the obtain api proposal - beeing a more integrated approach

Comment: You truly want to look into promises. It will save your hide in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a library that does what I'm asking for [ObtainJS](https://github.com/graphicore/obtainJS).

(Yes, the Library uses Promises BUT not as others proposed in their ansewers here)

Reposting the Readme.md:

## ObtainJS

ObtainJS is a micro framework to bring together asynchronous and 
synchronous JavaScript code. It helps you to Don't Repeat Yourself 
(DRY) if you are developing a library with interfaces for both 
blocking/synchronous and non-blocking/asynchronous execution models.

### As a *USER*

of a library that was implemented with ObtainJS you won't have to learn
a lot. Typically a function defined using ObtainJS has as first argument
the switch, that lets you choose the execution path, followed by its normal
arguments:

```
// readFile has an obtainJS API:
function readFile(obtainAsyncExecutionSwitch, path) { /* ... */ }
```

#### execute synchronously

If the obtainSwitch is a falsy value readFile will execute synchronously
and return the result directly.

```
var asyncExecution = false, result;
try {
    result = readFile(asyncExecution, './file-to-read.js');
} catch(error) {
    // handle the error
}
// do something with result
```

#### execute asynchronously

If the obtainSwitch is a truthy value readFile will execute asynchronously
and *always* return a Promise.

See [Promises at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
var asyncExecution = true, promise;

promise = readFile(asyncExecution, './file-to-read.js');
promise.then(
    function(result) {
        // do something with result
    },
    function(error){
        // handle the error
    }
)

// Alternatively, use the returned promise directly:

readFile(asyncExecution, './file-to-read.js')
    .then(
        function(result) {
            // do something with result
        },
        function(error){
            // handle the error
        }
    )
```

You can use a callback based api, too. Note that the Promise is returned anyways.

```
var asyncExecution;

function unifiedCallback(error, result){
    if(error)
        // handle the error
    else
        // do something with result
}

asyncExecution = {unified: unifiedCallback}

readfile(asyncExecution, './file-to-read.js');
```

or with a separate callback and errback

````
var asyncExecution;

function callback(result) {
    // do something with result
}

function errback(error) {
    // handle the error
}

var asyncExecution = {callback: callback, errback: errback}
readfile(asyncExecution, './file-to-read.js');

```
````

### As a smart ;-) *LIBRARY AUTHOR*

who's going to implement a API using with ObtainJS the work is a bit more.
Stay with me.

The behavior above is achieved by defining a twofold dependency tree: one
for the actions  of the synchronous execution path and one for the actions
of the  asynchronous execution path.

Actions are small functions with dependencies on the results of other 
actions. The asynchronous execution path will fallback to synchronous
actions if there is no asynchronous action defined for a dependency. 
*You wouldn't define an asynchronous action if its synchronous
equivalent is non-blocking*. This is where you **DRY**!

So, what you do, for example, is splitting your synchronous and blocking 
method in small function-junks. These junks depend on the results of each
other. Then you define a non-blocking AND asynchronous junk for each 
synchronous AND blocking junk. The rest does obtainJS for you. Namely:

- creating a switch for synchronous or asynchronous execution
- resolving the dependency tree
- executing the junks in the right order
- providing you with the results via:

  - return value when using the synchronous path
  - promises OR callbacks (your choice!) when using the asynchronous path

#### Here is the readFile function

from above, taken directly from working code at
[ufoJS](https://github.com/graphicore/ufoJS/blob/master/lib/tools/io/staticBrowserREST.js)

```
define(['ufojs/obtainJS/lib/obtain'], function(obtain) {

    // obtain.factory creates our final function
    var readFile = obtain.factory(
        // this is the synchronous dependency definition
        {
            // this action is NOT in the async tree, the async execution
            // path will fall back to this method
            uri: ['path', function _path2uri(path) {
                return path.split('/').map(encodeURIComponent).join('/')
            }]
            // synchronous AJAX request
          , readFile:['uri', function(path) {
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open('GET', path, false);
                request.send(null);

                if(request.status !== 200)
                    throw _errorFromRequest(request);

                return request.responseText;
            }]
        }
      ,
      // this is the asynchronous dependency definition
      {
            // aynchronous AJAX request
            readFile:['uri', '_callback', function(path, callback) {
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
                  , result
                  , error
                  ;
                request.open('GET', path, true);

                request.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
                    if (request.readyState != 4 /*DONE*/)
                        return;

                    if (request.status !== 200)
                        error = _errorFromRequest(request);
                    else
                        result = request.responseText
                    callback(error, result)
                }
                request.send(null);
            }]
        }
      // this are the "regular" function arguments
      , ['path']
      // this is the "job", a driver function that receives as first
      // argument the obtain api. A method that the name of an action or
      // of an argument as input and returns its result
      // Note that job is potentially called multiple times during
      // asynchronoys execution
      , function(obtain, path){ return obtain('readFile'); }
    );
})
```

#### a skeleton

```
var myFunction = obtain.factory(
    // sync actions
    {},
    // async actions
    {},
    // arguments
    [],
    //job
    function(obtain){}
);
```

#### action/getter definition

```
// To define a getter we give it a name provide a definition array.
{
    // sync

    sum: ['arg1', 'arg2',
    // the last item in the definition array is always the action/getter itself.
    // it is called when all dependencies are resolved
    function(arg1, arg2) {
        // function body.
        var value = arg1 + arg2
        return value
    }]
}

// For asynchronous getters you have different options:
{
    // async

    // the special name "_callback" will inject a callback function
    sample1: ['arg1',  '_callback', function(arg1, callback) {
            // callback(error, result)
        }],
    // you can order separate callback and errback when using both special
    // names "_callback" and "_errback"
    sample2: ['arg1',  '_callback', '_errback', function(arg1, callback, errback) {
            // errback(error)
            // callback(result)
        }],
    // return a promise
    sample3: ['arg1', function(arg1) {
            var promise = new Promise(/* do what you have to*/);

            return promise
        }]
}
```

The items in the definition array before the action are the dependencies
their values are going to be injected into the call to action, when
available.

If the type of an dependency **is not a string**: It's injected as a value
directly. This way you can effectively do currying.

If the type of the value **is a string**: It's looked up in the dependency
tree for the current execution path(sync or async).

- If its name is defined as an caller-argument (in the third argument of obtain.factory) the value
  is taken from the invoking call.
- If its name is defined as the name of another action, that action is
  executed and its return value is used as a parameter. An action will
  executed only once per run, later invocations will return a cached value.

  - If the  execution path is asynchronous obtain will first look for a
    asynchronous action definition. If that is not found it falls back
    to a synchronous definition.

If you wish to pass a String as value to your getter you must define it as
an instance of obtain.Argument:  `new obtain.Argument('mystring argument is not a getter')`

#### A more complete example

from [ufoLib/glifLib/GlyphSet.js](https://github.com/graphicore/ufoJS/blob/master/lib/ufoLib/glifLib/GlyphSet.js)

Note that: obtainJS is aware of the host object and propagates `this`
correctly to all actions.

```
    /**
     * Read the glif from I/O and cache it. Return a reference to the
     * cache object: [text, mtime, glifDocument(if alredy build by this.getGLIFDocument)]
     *
     * Has the obtainJS sync/async api.
     */
GlypSet.prototype._getGLIFcache = obtain.factory(
    { //sync
        fileName: ['glyphName', function fileName(glyphName) {
            var name = this.contents[glyphName];
            if(!(glyphName in this.contents) || this.contents[glyphName] === undefined)
                throw new KeyError(glyphName);
            return this.contents[glyphName]
        }]
      , glyphNameInCache: ['glyphName', function(glyphName) {
            return glyphName in this._glifCache;
        }]
      , path: ['fileName', function(fileName) {
            return [this.dirName, fileName].join('/');
        }]
      , mtime: ['path', 'glyphName', function(path, glyphName) {
            try {
                return this._io.getMtime(false, path);
            }
            catch(error) {
                if(error instanceof IONoEntryError)
                    error = new KeyError(glyphName, error.stack);
                throw error;
            }
        }]
      , text: ['path', 'glyphName', function(path, glyphName) {
            try {
                return this._io.readFile(false, path);
            }
            catch(error) {
                if(error instanceof IONoEntryError)
                    error = new KeyError(glyphName, error.stack);
                throw error;
            }
        }]
      , refreshedCache: ['glyphName', 'text', 'mtime',
        function(glyphName, text, mtime) {
            return (this._glifCache[glyphName] = [text, mtime]);
        }]
    }
    //async getters
  , {
        mtime: ['path', 'glyphName', '_callback',
        function(path, glyphName, callback) {
            var _callback = function(error, result){
                if(error instanceof IONoEntryError)
                    error = new KeyError(glyphName, error.stack);
                callback(error, result)
            }
            this._io.getMtime({unified: _callback}, path);
        }]
      , text: ['path', 'glyphName', '_callback',
        function(path, glyphName, callback){
            var _callback = function(error, result) {
                if(error instanceof IONoEntryError)
                    error = new KeyError(glyphName, error.stack);
                callback(error, result)
            }
            this._io.readFile({unified: _callback}, path);
        }
      ]
    }
    , ['glyphName']
    , function job(obtain, glyphName) {
        if(obtain('glyphNameInCache')) {
            if(obtain('mtime').getTime() === this._glifCache[glyphName][1].getTime()) {
                // cache is fresh
                return this._glifCache[glyphName];
            }
        }
        // still here? need read!
        // refreshing the cache:
        obtain('refreshedCache')
        return this._glifCache[glyphName];
    }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking I/O in node.js then most I/O methods have a synchronous version.

There is no direct conversion from Asynchronicity To Synchronicity. I can think of two approaches:

1. Have each asynchronous method run a polling loop waiting for the async task to complete before returning.
2. Drop the idea of mimicking synchronous code and instead invest in better coding patterns (such as promises)

To illustrate I will assume option 2 is a better choice. The following example uses [Q promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) (easily installed with `npm install q`.

The idea behind promises is that although they are asynchronous the return object is a *promise* for a value as if it was a normal function.

```
// Normal function
function foo(input) {
  return "output";
}

// With promises
function promisedFoo(input) {
  // Does stuff asynchronously
  return promise;
}
```

The first function takes an input and returns a result. The second example takes an input and immediately returns a promise which will eventually resolve to a value when the async task finishes. You then manage this promise as follows:

```
var promised_value = promisedFoo(input);
promised_value.then(function(value) {
  // Yeah, we now have a value!
})
.fail(function(reason) {
  // Oh nos.. something went wrong. It passed in a reason
});
```

Using promises you no longer have to worry when something will happen. You can easily chain promises so things happen synchronously without insane nested callbacks or 100 named functions.

It well worth learning about. Remember promises are meant to make async code behave like sync code even though it isn't blocking.

Comment: I will have a look at promises and Q promises, however I'm not shure yet if I wan't to drop the synchronous version of the API.

Comment: @Lasse Promises is the way to go if you want to mimic synchronous API as close as possible.

Comment: Its definitely not about mimicking, although if I would drop the *real* synchronous API promises would be fine, I think. A possible solution would be to leave the synchronous API as it is and to write  the asynchronous API *extra* using promises. Dropping the synchronous API is not an answer to my question.

Comment: There is no way to block asynchronous code. You can have a thread loop over till something is completed to essentially block but the core idea behind asynchronous code it that it is non-blocking. That is why I suggested to re think the problem. If you already have a synchronous "API" as you put it, Then I don't see what the problem is in the first place. It's easy to go from sync -> async style. Just not the other way around nor should you. I think there are ways to handle threads in node but not sure.

Comment: I know that there is no way to block non-blocking code and I did not ask for it nor do I want to do such things.
I'm looking for a way to implement both: a real blocking api and a real non-blocking api. The library I'm porting is only blocking and I want to keep that for legacy reasons. Plus, I wan't to add a non-blocking api.
I think it would be good to keep both implementations close, because the algorithms don't need to change and because I believe its good to have the same thing happening in one place only (not at any price of course, that's why I'm asking).

Comment: Um then you can just wrap the sync API in setTimeout to make it async. no?

Comment: It will run in the browser, too the sync api would block the ui and in node it would block nevertheless, just the programming paradigm could be shifted. So wrapping into setTimeout is not an option.

Comment: @Sukima would you mind to modify your answer to be an actual answer to my question?

Answer (score 0):

Write lower level API using promises that takes async/sync flag.

Higher level async API returns these promises directly (while also working with async callbacks like it's 1970).

Higher level sync API unwraps the value synchronously from the promise and returns the value or throws the error.

<sup>(Examples use [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) which is orders of magnitude faster and has more features at the cost of file size compared to Q, although that might not be ideal for browsers.)</sup>

Low level api that is not exposed:

```
//lowLevelOp calculates 1+1 and returns the result
//There is a 20% chance of throwing an error

LowLevelClass.prototype.lowLevelOp = function(async, arg1, arg2) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (Math.random() < 0.2) {
            throw new Error("random error");
        }
        if (!async) resolve(1+1);
        else {
        //Async
            setTimeout(function(){
                resolve(1+1);
            }, 50);
        }
    });
};
```

High level exposed API that works synchronously, using promises or callbacks:

```
HighLevelClass.prototype.opSync = function(arg1, arg2) {
    var inspection = 
        this.lowLevel.lowLevelOp(false, arg1, arg2).inspect();

    if (inspection.isFulfilled()) {
        return inspection.value();
    }
    else {
        throw inspection.error();
    }
};

HighLevelClass.prototype.opAsync = function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    //returns a promise as well as accepts callback.
    return this.lowLevel.lowLevelOp(true, arg1, arg2).nodeify(callback);
};
```

---

You can automatically generate the high level api for synchronous methods:

```
var LowLevelProto = LowLevelClass.prototype;

Object.keys(LowLevelProto).filter(function(v) {
    return typeof LowLevelProto[v] === "function";
}).forEach(function(methodName) {
    //If perf is at all a concern you really must do this with a 
    //new Function instead of closure and reflection
    var method = function() {
        var inspection = this.lowLevel[methodName].apply(this.lowLevel, arguments);

        if (inspection.isFulfilled()) {
            return inspection.value();
        }
        else {
            throw inspection.error();
        }
    };

    HighLevelClass.prototype[methodName + "Sync" ] = method;
});
```

Comment: I think promises are seventies, too ;-) See: 
["The term promise was proposed in 1976 … "](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_%28programming%29)

Comment: @Lasse By now literally every other language is using promises (note that `async/await` counts as promises) except Javascript which is slowly catching up... and one probably cannot ever release library that doesn't work with callbacks

Comment: right, it has been *not so common* with JavaScript. But what I can see with this question is that promises are very popular now and many people think its the answer for any problem related to asynchronous programming.
It should be noted that the promises-"hype" is not about callbacks vs. promises. Promises take callbacks, too `foo.then(calllback)` it's about promises vs. continuation-passing style.

This question is not about these styles, and while a good answer could use promises in one way or the other I don't think its important for the answer to endorse one style.

Comment: @Lasse Promises are not alternative style to callbacks but an abstraction that enables synchronous patterns to be applied to asynchronous code. Callbacks do not do that at all. To the uninitiated it certainly looks like "promises take callbacks too" (even though that's not true, you can also tap into the promise value with `await` or `yield`). If you view promises as alternative callbacks rather than an internal DSL you will not get any benefits from using them. I wrote about this in promise anti-patterns https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns

Comment: don't get me wrong I'm not anti-promises or anything. I will definitely use promises in the future in some situations and I'll test your proposal in a more demanding example to see how well promises perform. I'm just getting the feeling that promises are the new [Golden_hammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_hammer) for some people. Talking about the *uninitiated* and the way you use the word *callback* is not helpful at all. Promises obviously take callbacks. Maybe you mean [CPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) when writing *callback*